# Highchart chinese colon display incorrect when exporting

Tags: highcharts, export

When exporting chart in Highchart, all my characters are displayed well, except Chinese colon. 
Do I need to set something specical?
Even in the highchart exporting example from its site, there is still the problem

Please see an example in http://jsfiddle.net/warmwind/Prah7/2

When setting title as below, it cannot be export correctly

```
title: {
        text: 'Exporting it：colon in between'
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is wrong with the defautlt font on the export-server for this chinese character. Please, specify a font-family for your title. Like this,

```
title: {
    text: 'Exporting it：colon in between',
    style: {
            "font-family":'verdana'
    },            
},
```

There´s reported an issue for this, see https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2120

Comment: The Chinese colon issue has been fixed, but there are some other Chinese characters cannot be exported, e.g. [http://jsfiddle.net/8knFh](http://jsfiddle.net/8knFh)